# Fundamental groupoid of a Kan complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $X\in \operatorname{sSet}$ be a Kan complex. This gives rise to the *fundamental groupoid* $\Pi(X)$ of $X$. I am having trouble seeing why the composition in $\Pi(X)$ is well defined.

If $y\in X[2]$ is a 2-simplex, then the composition $d_0(y)\circ d_2(y)$ is defined to be $d_1(y)$. So if $y'\in X[2]$ is another 2-simplex with $d_0(y)=d_0(y')$ and $d_2(y)=d_2(y')$, then why do we have $d_1(y)=d_1(y')$ in $\Pi(X)$?

Clearly we need to define a horn $\Lambda^n\to X$ and use the Kan complex property to fill it to get a $2$-simplex in $X$ which gives $d_1(y)=d_1(y')$ but I just can't figure out which horn does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are $2$-simplices sharing their $1$-horn, say $x\xrightarrow{\alpha} y\xrightarrow{\beta} z$, then you may glue them together to a $1$-horn in a $3$-simplex by taking $\sigma$ as the $3$-face, $\tau$ as the $2$-face, and $s_1(\beta)$ as the $0$-face. The $1$-face of any $3$-simplex extending this horn then constitutes a homotopy between $d_2(\sigma)$ and $d_2(\tau)$.

Note that this uses inner horn fillings only and works for any $\infty$-category, see [Proposition 1.3.2.7 in HTT](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/highertopoi.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! The 1-face of the 3-simplex gives a homotopy between $d_1(\sigma)$ and $d_1(\tau)$, right? I am confused by the following: To get a well defined simplicial map $\Lambda^3_1\to X$ we need that the values on the edges where the $2$-simplices meet are the same for both $2$-simplices, right?

Comment: So for instance, don't we need that $d_0( \text{2-face} ) = d_0(\text{0-face})$? However, as far as I can tell, $d_0( \text{2-face} ) = \alpha$ whereas $d_0(\text{0-face})=d_0s_1(\beta)=s_0d_0(\beta)=\beta$.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas: The overlapping condition between the $2$-face $\tau$ and the $0$-face $s_1(\beta)$ would be $d_0(\tau)=d_1(s_1(\beta))$. Does this help? Perhaps it's worth drawing a picture.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thank you!